# response message in SOAPUI is displayed encrypted

Tags: https, soapui

I try to test a web-service using SOAPUI using a HTTPS endpoint. The problem is that the response message is displayed encrypted. What do I need to configure in SOAPUI in order to see the actual response message?

I tried various settings (e.g. in preferences I tried to set an exported certificate from Firefox), but no luck so far. Note that the security of the web-service is implemented using a username/password mechanism in the SOAP header and the same call works fine on a HTTP endpoint (we have a couple of environments available).

Comment: Hmm... In my case, if I send to https, I can read the response.  Is there some encryption being done in addition to regular SSL?

Comment: Are there any other clients that DO work with this service?

Comment: The Java application can access the same web service just fine. When I use SOAPUI to play with some test data I run into this problem.

Comment: can u paste in request/response, so that we can better understand what ur trying to convey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had this same problem and found the solution here:

http://www.eviware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2601&p=10862&hilit=encrypted+response+https#p10862

Basically you need to go into file->preferences->http settings and uncheck the 'Response compression' checkbox.